# Loading local ckeditor plugins when a CDN is used, and Chrome cache

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome, ckeditor

Writing an asp.net mvc app and playing with ckeditor (4.7.2) as a newbie. I load ckeditor from the cdn so I have to configure it to be able to load plugins locally, as [per the doc](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/):

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('name', '@Url.Content("~/scripts/ckeditor/plugins/name")',
'plugin.js');
```

But if I do this, the browser tries to load this:

```
localhost/scripts/ckeditor/plugins/name?t=H7HDplugin.js
```

Checking in the browser console, I see also that all ckeditor files are loaded that way, with this appended ?t=H7HD query string.

The only workaround I found was to use this form instead:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('name',
  '@Url.Content("~/scripts/ckeditor/plugins/name/plugin.js")', '');
```

which loads the file correctly:

```
localhost/scripts/ckeditor/plugins/name/plugin.js?t=H7HD
```

Is this a bug? Should the first form build the URL in the correct order? Or is there something I missed?

**Update**: realized that the doc puts a final slash to the path. If I add it, this also fixes the issue, keeping the query string at the end. But this does not explain why this query string exists and why ckeditor does not check for this ending slash.

And this brings me to a secondary question. During development, modifying files in Visual Studio is enough to make Chrome reload them without any action from me. But in the case of plugins loaded by ckeditor, Chrome keeps the old version. I have to clear the cache of the browser, each time I want to be sure I have the latest version. Is there any way to fix this? I think this is a related question because I first thought this ?t=... was a mechanism to reload the files by bypassing the cache, except that here, the value behing 't' does not change.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in the `addExternal()` method as [per documentation](https://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins-method-addExternal) is:

> path : String
>   The path of the folder containing the resource.

If the path is `/scripts/ckeditor/plugins/name?t=H7HD` then the last parameter (plugin file, `plugin.js`) is concatenated with it.

Comment: I'm not adding "?t=H7HD" to the path. All urls loaded by ckeditor have this.

Comment: Ops, indeed CKEditor behaves just like you described in case of having a path without trailing slash at the end. So the immediate solution for this issue is to add slash at the end of the path to a plugin folder. I reopened the issue you reported: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/917

Answer (score 0):

as per the documentation, this is a timestamp property:
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-timestamp